# Cassandra: copy null

Tags: database, cassandra, null, copy, nosql

I have problem with COPY command in Cassandra.
I try move my old database on new server but when I use COPY FROM I receives error:

```
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'null',  given up without retries
```

Some fields are null and the need to keep this informations.
CSV I created with COPY TO:

```
COPY tabel TO './db.csv' WITH NULL='null'
```

If I try make CSV without NULL='null' I receives error:

```
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - invalid literal for int() with base 10: '',  given up without retries
```

How I can assign null to int ?
Cassandra version:
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.6 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]

Comment: What happens when you try your `COPY` command with `NULL=0`?

Comment: All empty fields are filled 0. But I cant have zeros :(

Answer (score 1):

I have found a bug description in JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11549

And the patch worked for me both on Linux and Windows. I have just manually replaced one line of the code in the given file:

https://github.com/stef1927/cassandra/commit/6e7664380bb6ddea37efd5f866b7631fdc84bdac

Does it work for you as well?