# Cassandra COPY all as insert

Tags: database, insert, cassandra, copy

I need know how I can get all Insert Into method in cassandra. Devcenter allows you to copy all as insert but there is a limit 1000 entries.
So how can I get a list of inserts ?

Comment: you want to copy your data?

Comment: yes, i need copy data

Comment: use COPY command from cqlsh

Comment: but it is copy to csv format. I need see INSERT method.

Answer (score 0):

`COPY All as Insert` is devCenter specific functionality and is used for only small dataset.
The functionality is not available in cqlsh and using such functionality might lead to issues when migrating to poduction. 
If using for development/testing purpose only you can modify your query in devCenter as `Select * from table limit 5000`.

**Note:** Replace 5000 with number of your choice. Even if you COPY your data to CSV you can import it back (So Insrt statement is not required).

Comment: With csv backup I have this problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431860/cassandra-copy-null?noredirect=1#comment62368877_37431860

Comment: for backup you can use cassandra snapshots. Above solution is in no way going to help in production

Comment: Ok,but with snapshot I have problem with copy data on new server (no cluster). How I should move data (on production server) to new server (test server) ?

Comment: check sstableloader

Answer (score 0):

DevCenter version 1.6.0 has the ability to export all of the query result rows (CSV or INSERT statements) in the dataset directly to a file.

Right-click in the results view and select "Export all results to File as CSV" or "Export all results to File as Insert".